# Chaining method - don't override value if the function is called more then once

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to recreate something similar to the CodeIgniter active record. My goal is following:

When this is called:

```
echo $messages->select()->from()->where('user', 'foo')->where('dateadded', 'today');
```

it needs to create two where conductions (WHERE user = foo AND dateadded = today). But at the moment I am getting only the value of the second function called (WHERE dateadded = today). How can I do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
abstract class DatabaseQuery extends Database
{

    protected $_tablename;
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_dbSelect    = '';
    protected $_dbFrom      = '';
    protected $_dbJoin      = '';
    protected $_dbWhere     = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $query = '';
        $query .= $this->_dbSelect . PHP_EOL;
        $query .= $this->_dbFrom . PHP_EOL;
        $query .= $this->_dbJoin . PHP_EOL;
        $query .= $this->_dbWhere . PHP_EOL;

        return $query;
    }

    public function select($select = null)
    {
        if($select === null):
            $this->_dbSelect = "SELECT *";
        else:
            $this->_dbSelect = "SELECT {$select}";
        endif;

        return $this;
    }

    public function from($from = null)
    {
        if($from === null):
            $this->_dbFrom = "FROM {$this->_tablename}";
        else:
            $this->_dbFrom = "FROM {$from}";
        endif;

        return $this;

    }

    public function join($table, $on)
    {
        if(is_string($join))
            $this->_dbJoin = "JOIN {$table} ON {$on}";

        return $this;
    }

    public function where($field, $value = null)
    {
        if(!is_array($field)):
            $this->_dbWhere = "WHERE " . $field . ' = :' . $value;
        else:
            $where = 'WHERE ';

            foreach($field as $key => $value):
                $where .= $key . ' = :' . $key . ' AND ';
            endforeach;

            $this->_dbWhere = rtrim($where, ' AND ');
        endif;

        return $this;

    }
```

Comment: Wheres the rest of your code.

Comment: This is it for now. I have Database class, but is a standard PDO class. And Message class is empty with only __construct function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need some sort of a trigger to run the query at the end

```
$messages->select()->from()->where('user', 'foo')->where('dateadded', 'today')->get();
```

you can smooth things up in the trigger for example

```
<?php
class QueryBuilder{
    private $_dbWhere;

    public function where($field, $value = null)
    {
        if(!is_array($field)):
            $this->_dbWhere .= $field . ' = :' . $value . ' AND ';
        else:
            foreach($field as $key => $value):
                $this->_dbWhere .= $key . ' = :' . $key . ' AND ';
            endforeach;
        endif;

        return $this;
    }

    // your trigger this will get the result for the class user
    public function get()
    {
        // smooth things up (remove last AND ) 
        $this->_dbWhere = " WHERE " . rtrim($this->_dbWhere, ' AND ');

        // build the query select . from . where

        // and return the result (in this case print _dbWhere)
        echo $this->_dbWhere;
    }
}
```

this will work

```
$db = new QueryBuilder;

$db->where('user', 'foo')->where('dateadded', 'today')->get();
```

However, your trying to reinvent the wheels there are tons of beautiful query builders out there take a look at [`Laravel's Query Builder`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) to get some inspiration

Comment: Yea, I know. I am experimenting with PHP and I want to learn how to work with chaining and kinda want to build my db driver. Just for fun. This is working :)

Comment: @Sasha reinventing the wheels is good for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

Would that fullfill your needs ?

```
 public function where($field, $value = null)
    {
        if(this->_dbWhere == ''){
              $this->_dbWhere .= "WHERE ";
        } else {
               $this->_dbWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        if(!is_array($field)){

            $this->_dbWhere =  . $field . ' = :' . $value;
        }else{

            foreach($field as $key => $value):
                $where .= $key . ' = :' . $key . ' AND ';
            endforeach;

            $this->_dbWhere = rtrim($where, ' AND ');
        }

        return $this;

    }
```

Comment: Nope, the result is still the same.